# Parsing CSV files to arrays from very large sources in java

Tags: java, parsing, csv, optimization

I have a parser that works fine on smaller files of approx. 60000 lines or less but I have to parse a CSV file with over 10 million lines and this method just isn't working it hangs every 100 thousand lines for 10 seconds and I assume its the split method, Is there a faster way to parse data from a CSV to a string array?

Code in question:

```
    String[][] events = new String[rows][columns];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(csvFileName);

    int j = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext()){
        events[j] = sc.nextLine().split(",");
        j++;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure, you want to keep that many entries in memory at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

your code won't parse CSV files reliably. What if you had ',' or a line separator in a value? This is also very slow.

Get [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to parse your files. It is 3 times faster than Apache Commons CSV, has many more features and we use it to process files with billions of rows.

To parse all rows into a list of Strings:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); //lots of options here, check the documentation

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File("path/to/input.csv")));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 1):

as a rule of thumb, using libraries is usually more efficient than in-house development.  There are several libraries that provide reading/parsing csv files. One of the more popular ones is [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a library I've just released: [sesseltjonna-csv](https://github.com/skjolber/sesseltjonna-csv)

It dynamically generates a CSV parser + databinding at runtime using ASM for improved performance.